# what could cause the Exception iText.Kernel.PdfException: 'Unknown PdfException.' when calling GetEncodedPKCS7?

Tags: .net, pdf, itext

Until "2023-09-19" everything worked fine. Today, the exact same code fails always  with the error

SocketException: No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it 173.82.18.238:443

[Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EEAFB.jpg)

I have no clue about the cause of this error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> SocketException: No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it 173.82.18.238:443

Apparently there was some issue connecting to `173.82.18.238` via https. In the context of `GetEncodedPKCS7` this should mean that your code attempts to retrieve a time stamp from there. This assumption also is supported by pointing a browser to https://173.82.18.238/ - a FreeTSA web page comes up.

Have you meanwhile tried again? Maybe the TSA server software was offline when the exception occurred at your end.

If the issue has not yet resolved by itself, you should check your network settings. If that doesn't help, you should eventually contact the people who run that TSA: If you requested too many time stamps from that free server in the past, you may have been blocked.

Comment: Yes, i retried again and it worked fine and keeps working.

Comment: Indeed i've requested too many time stamps from that free server, so i suspect that  i have been blocked.